# hitting save button adds extra one more empty field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a rules component where any number of rules can be added and that added rules will be shown either along with the additional add feature for the rules. There is no problem while adding, removing the rule field but when posting the data to the server, the data gets posted but one more extra empty field is generated in the client side. I don't know how and why its happening.

Here is the code

```
const _id = 0;

function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4();
}

const removeByKey = (obj, deleteKey) =>
  Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key !== deleteKey).reduce((result, current) => {
    result[current] = obj[current];
    return result;
  }, {});

class Rules extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      rules: { ruleAndregulations: {} },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadRules();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.rules.size && nextProps.rules !== this.props.rules) {
      nextProps.rules
        .entrySeq()
        .map(([key, value]) => {
          console.log('key', key, value);
          this.setState(
            state => ({
              rules: {
                ...state.rules,
                ruleAndregulations: {
                  ...state.rules.ruleAndregulations,
                  [value.get('_id')]: { _id: value.get('_id'), value: value.get('value') }
                }
              }
            })
          );
        })
        .toArray();
    }
  }

  handleAddRules = e => {
    this.setState({
      rules: {
        ...this.state.rules,
        ruleAndregulations: {
          ...this.state.rules.ruleAndregulations,
          [guid()]: {
            _id: guid(),
            value: ''
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  handleRemoveRules = (e, num) => {
    this.setState({
      rules: {
        ...this.state.rules,
        ruleAndregulations: removeByKey(this.state.rules.ruleAndregulations, num)
      }
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      rules: {
        ...this.state.rules,
        ruleAndregulations: {
          ...this.state.rules.ruleAndregulations,
          [e.target.name]: {
            _id: e.target.name,
            value: e.target.value
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  handleSave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const ruleObj = { rule_regulations: [] };
    const { ruleAndregulations } = this.state.rules;
    Object.keys(ruleAndregulations).map(val =>
      ruleObj.rule_regulations.push(ruleAndregulations[val].value)
    );
    this.props.postRules(ruleObj);
  };

  render() {
    const { rules } = this.state;
    console.log('state', this.state);
    return (
      <div className="basic-property">
        Add Rules and Regulations
        <span className="circleInputUi" onClick={this.handleAddRules}>
          +
        </span>
        {rules &&
          rules.ruleAndregulations &&
          <RulesInputContainer
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            handleRemoveRules={this.handleRemoveRules}
            handleSave={this.handleSave}
            value={rules.ruleAndregulations}
          />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Rules);
```

reducer for posting is

```
  case POST_RULES_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .merge({
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          response: action.response.message
        })
        .update('rules', rules => rules.push(fromJS(action.response.data)));
```

for code in more detail

https://gist.github.com/MilanRgm/7f744ee27df7e5d17410ffcba99fb89c

After posting I get the following data in componentWillReceiveProps

[image]

When using concat

a) When very first rule is added

[image]

b) When second rule added

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are `push`ing a List into a List, instead of `concat`ing it. In your reducer, try

```
.update('rules', rules => rules.concat(fromJS(action.response.data)));
```

Comment: When I use concat and add the rule, for example there is alread one rule, If I add another rule say rule 2 then i get rule 1, rule2, rule1, rule2

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @milan what is the backend returning, all rules, or just the rules you posted?